# Find cells with specific values, then retrieve values that are X # of cells away, multiple times and skipping those already done

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

all! I couldn't find an answer that covers all my requirements, or at least I wasn't looking for the right terminology. Hopefully this is something that's possible. I'd like to use a formula for this if possible but if it needs to be a macro then so be it. I'll try my best to explain the problem. Fake values are used to protect workplace data. It's Excel 2007 and I don't have permission to use any add-ons.

I have two sheets, let's call them Source and Target. The values on these sheets change constantly but the layout remains mostly the same.
Source A1:B1 are just headings. Let's say A1 is Item and B1 is Client.
Item has a unique value in each row. They never repeat. They are always in alphabetical order. Client does repeat and is in no particular order. Clients and Items are added/deleted all the time.

EXAMPLE SOURCE:

[SOURCE example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0IuK.jpg)

Target's top row are for headings. Of these headings, A1 is Client and that column lists each of the Clients once each in alphabetical order. Clients are added/removed from both sheets frequently.

EXAMPLE TARGET:

[TARGET EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHh0I.jpg)

Now with that all out of the way, **this is what I need to do**: I want some way for Target to automatically grab Items from Source and place them in the appropriate row on Target. So far I haven't been able to get it to recognize an Item that it already grabbed.

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like Index/Match would do it...Please show any code or formulas you've attempted to use

Comment: How would you populate column A in target sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Source!$A:$A,SMALL(IF($A2=Source!$B:$B,ROW(Source!$B:$B),99999999),COLUMN(A2))),"")
```

Array Formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time
in B2 under the first item in Target
next to the first client
You can drag it in the row and in the column